# Can ImageMagick number output files with two digits?

Tags: imagemagick

I use the following command to extract pages from PDF files into independent JPG files before inserting them into videos:

```
convert.exe -density 96 -resize 640x480 input.pdf +adjoin -alpha remove -alpha off output.jpg
```

As a result, files are numbered output-1.jpg, output-2.jpg and so on, which means that for PDFs that have more than 10 pages, the first ten are not listed first.

I'd rather that the filenames be numbered as output-01.jpg, output-02.jpg so they come before the rest of the files.

Does someone know if ImageMagick can be told to use two digits when naming output files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the following:

```
convert.exe -density 96 -resize 640x480 input.pdf +adjoin -alpha remove -alpha off output-%02d.jpg
```

The `%02d` makes sure the number is zero padded to 2 digits.